# The key with no door

Tags: visual, real

I was given this key, along with an attached seating assignment, at a wedding reception.  While many guests assumed it was merely a decorative key, a few clever guests quickly realized the truth.  The bride and groom had ensured that guests would have a key to an important treasure, one needed for their own celebrations!

What does this key open?

Hint 1:

> It's common to avoid sharing photographs of a key blade because doing so reveals a lot of information about the lock.

Hint 2:

> The provided photograph does a poor job hiding the shape of the key blade.

[image: The key]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a

> Bottle opener! (Hence why it doesn't open a door)

The treasure here is therefore

> Alcohol, which is often used to celebrate.

The key blade will look something like this:

> [image]

Comment: I knew this was easy, but I was hoping it would last more than 5 minutes.  I'll accept once SE lets me.  I guess I'll stick to asking individual friends what it opens; even without hiding the blade, it often stumps people.

Comment: @Brian my immediate thought from the celebrations clue was some sort of alcohol, so a quick search led to wedding bottle openers, so I probably wouldn't have got it without that!

Comment: Good one! [Wikincidentally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_key)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: Thank you for the info and great job on such a fast solve.

Comment: @Brian No matter how easy it was or how long it last, this one is just pure fun ^_^ Thanks a lot.